# View in the center of layout if there's enough space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout and need to place one of the views in the center. It's easy. The problem is that I also have some other views which need to be positioned to the top of the screen.

**Problem:** If there's enough space it looks ok, but when the screen is too small the top and center elements **overlap**.

**Question:** How to push the "centered" element down if the screen is to small?

The original layout is very complex, I prepared an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/theOneAtTheTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some long text which may overlap the lower view. Some long text which may overlap the lower view."
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/theOneInTheMiddlep"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some long text which may overlap the upper view. Some long text which may overlap the upper view. "
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a little simulation. The middle picture shows how it looks on a small screen, and the pictures on sides show the desired situation.
[image]

Comment: put a screen shot and the layout code.

Comment: I posted xml, will prepare an image in a minute. Original xml is to complex, it would be difficult to get the point

Comment: I'm afraid that this is a similar issue than in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242801/android-layout-alignment-issue which never got any answer at the time... I can't figure a solution yet...

Comment: Just a hunch: You are not using relative layouts enough...try harder. Put everything in a relative layout.

Comment: Well (if you're not being sarcastic), everything IS in a `RelativeLayout` and I doubt that nesting them would help...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm changing this answer completely. In case the desired alignment is vertical, you could put your code inside a RelativeLayout which will _fill_parent_ and will be *below* theOneAtTheTop. Inside it, you could put the view you want to be vertically center aligned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theOneAtTheTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Some long text which may overlap the lower view. Some long text which may overlap the lower view." />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/theOneAtTheTop" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/theOneInTheMiddlep"
            android:layout_width="200sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Some long text which may overlap the upper view. long text which may overlap the upper view. Some long text which may overlap the upper view.  " />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: To be honest I can't see a difference between your code and mine

Comment: Sry, it's because I've posted the wrong code (actually, yours before modifications)

Comment: Well, my answer is similar with Vinay's, what make me ask: you want the view centered with the horizontal or vertical direction?

Comment: Vertically. The problem is that `layout_centerInParent` will override `layout_below` and vice versa, depending on which appeared in the code last.

Comment: Ok, it changes things and I edited the answer to match the question. Important to note that I just aligned centerVertical with the RelativeLayout parent, but another alignments could be used

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt you can do this directly in the layout file as a xml layout is not the place for such conditional logic. The only real situation where you could(I think) use the layout file would be if you knew the exact dimensions of the views involved plus the API level of the app would be `3.2`, creating a lot of layouts for different situations(which I really doubt).

If you center one of the views in a `RelativeLayout` it will be centered no matter what, it doesn't have the notion of overlaping views at the xml layout file level. In code is another thing.

Comment: Yeah, my thoughts exactly. But this platform surprised me many times (mostly in bad ways;)), so I still think this question is worth being asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just add `android:layout_below="@+id/theOneAtTheTop"`
 to the second TextView and you are good to go.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/theOneAtTheTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some long text which may overlap the lower view. Some long text which may overlap the lower view.Some long text which may overlap the lower view. Some long text which may overlap the lower view.Some long text which may overlap the lower view. Some long text which may overlap the lower view.Some long text which may overlap the lower view. Some long text which may overlap the lower view.Some long text which may overlap the lower view. Some long text which may overlap the lower view.Some long text which may overlap the lower view. Some long text which may overlap the lower view."
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/theOneInTheMiddlep"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/theOneAtTheTop"
    android:text="Some long text which may overlap the upper view. Some long text which may overlap the upper view. "
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will override `layout_centerInParent`, so `theOneInTheMiddle` it won't be in the center if the screen is big enough

Comment: Correct, My bad. Forgot the preference